# Default ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a `ListView` in an app that I'm making and I used a String to populate the `ListView` with a default message when the Activity starts:

```
String dMessage = "The list is empty";
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.add(dMessage);
```

Is there an easy way to make it so the default string is not clickable? When the user enters another string, via text input, that message is removed and replaced with a string that I do want click able so I don't want the whole `ListView` to not be clickable. I was hoping that I could use a `hint` like you can with `EditText` but I don't think that's possible

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish fully but can you set Listview to not be clickable when the default text is entered then when a user enters text revert it?

Ex:

```
adapter.add(dMessage);
listView.setClickable(false);
...
...
//User enters new text
listView.setClickable(true);
```

**edit:**

```
//As provided by Sam
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

**or**

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
// return false if default message is active : Boolean or some other check
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, however this code does not work, the default string is still clickable. I think I need to implement a `setClickable(false);` to the `adapter` but it doesn't have a method for that

Comment: have you tried also setting listView.setFocusable(False) at the same time?

Comment: Try using the code above. If you make a custom adapter you can return false when something is selected and have a Boolean to check if the default message is still up.

Comment: Didn't I already suggest your "edit"? Why do you override `isEnabled()` if you already told the Adapter that all of the items are disabled...

Comment: I was just working with him to find a solution and it steered that way over time. I was giving both options to try. I should have specified that either/or not both. I also wanted to give an example as to how isEnabled could work in his situation. I did not intend to step on any toes. Very sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but I can answer this question:

> Is there an easy way to make it so the default string is not clickable?

Create a custom Adapter by extending ArrayAdapter and override [`areAllItemsEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29):

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

If you only want certain rows to be clickable override [`isEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) as well.

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
Textview texView=new TextView("No Items To Display");

if(items.isEmpty())
    listview.setHeaderView(textView);
else
    listview.removeHeaderView(textView);
```

Comment: Code-only answers with "Try this" are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Please expand your answer.